# Como puedo crear una Cookie en Django

Tags: python, django

Quiero crear una cookie para guardar ciertos datos cuando el usuario inicia sesion. Se leer las cookies que existen con `request.COOKIES['cookie_name']` pero no soy capaz de crear una.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [Documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie)
 lo que debes hacer para enviar una cookie en la respuesta es precisamente, tomar la respuesta, y ayudarte del método `set_cookie`, el cual tiene los siguientes parámetros `key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/', domain=None, secure=None, httponly=False` y debes usarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
#  cuando estes enviando tu respuesta
...
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/html')
response.set_cookie('llave', 'valor')
```

Y lo recuperas tal como ya sabes hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo he conseguido!